# How to Clip Grid with Full Width Rectangle in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to Clip or create round corners for an image in Xamarin forms. Everything works as expected, but I am stuck how to allow the Grid Rectangle to take the full width. Now the Width is static.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="400" RowDefinitions="300,100" Margin="10,0">
                            <sh:Shadows Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                <sh:Shadows.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="sh:Shadows">
                                        <Setter Property="IsClippedToBounds" Value="False"/>
                                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Shades">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <sh:ShadeStack>
                                                    <sh:Shade BlurRadius="5" Offset="0,5" Color="{DynamicResource ThemeComplementary}" />
                                                </sh:ShadeStack>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </sh:Shadows.Resources>
                                <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="False" IsClippedToBounds="True"/>
                            </sh:Shadows>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Image Source="{Binding DailySupplicationBackgroundImageLink, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                </Image>
                                <Grid.Clip>
                                    <RoundRectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,300" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"/>
                                </Grid.Clip>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0" Text="Some Text here"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
```

I am looking to round the image only from two sides which is set in the inner grid as bellow.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" IsClippedToBounds="True">
                                <Image Source="{Binding DailySupplicationBackgroundImageLink, Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                </Image>
                                <Grid.Clip>
                                    <RoundRectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,300" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0"/> // Set Fill Width
                                </Grid.Clip>
                            </Grid>
```

This works fine but with static width to the `Rect`. I am looking to achieve below.

I know there are packages like `Pancake`, but I don't seem it necessary to use that package.

[image: Sample Image With radius corner from two sides only]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it from code behind.
Instead of clipping the Grid, I managed to clip the Image itself.
I still would be interested to find out how to do the same in XAML instead of code behind. I added below in Page SizeChanged event to take care of orientation.

```
private void MydayPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            image.Clip = new Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.RoundRectangleGeometry(new CornerRadius(10, 10, 0, 0), 
                new Rectangle
            {
                Width = Width-20,
                Height = 300,
                X = 0,
                Y = 0
            });
        }
```